# socket.emit reconnects client

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a messaging app that works the following way: one of the user sends a list of messages through socket.emit to the server, which then sends the messages to the intended receiver.

First time i tried using multiple emits for multiple messages sent all at once, but only the first as received, so i switched to using a list of messages.

Now, if the user sends a text message it will send a list with one object containing the information. If the user selects and sends one image as an attachment, the list of messages will have a list with an object with the data for an image; but if the user sends multiple images all at once, a list of objects, each containing the data for each image, will be sent, and the client on which the `socket.emit(sender, receiver, message_list)` is ran is forcefully reconnected.

This is what the code looks like:

```js
const divs = some_node.children;  // these are the elements that contain the information
let message_list = [];
let message_object;
for (let i=0; i<divs.length; i++) {
    message_object = {};
    const input = div.input_field.value;
    const source = divs[i].firstElementChild.firstElementChild.src;
    const time = `${(new Date()).getHours()}:${(new Date()).getMinutes()}`;
    
    if (input != null  &&  input.trim() != "") {
        // display the message on the sender's screen
        // ...
        message_object = {
            message: input,
            image: source,
            time: time
        };
    } else {
        // display the message on the sender's screen
        // ...
        message_object = {
            message: null,
            image: source,
            time: time
        };
    }
    // put the images on the sender's screen
    // ...
    message_list.push(message_object);
}
socket.emit("message-send", sender, receiver, message_list);
```

[Github repository.](https://github.com/Konstei/stack-overflow-code/)

Any help would be appreciated, i have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: I'd suggest you turn on both client and server socket.io advanced debugging to you can see what it is reporting.  That should show you when it connects, disconnects and reconnects and may give you some idea why.

Comment: @jfriend00 took your advice, it gives transport error and i still haven't figured out why, even in the socket framework docs i only found references to transport errors like 2 times

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you have the same exact version of the socket.io library on both client and server?  I believe mismatched versions can cause a transport error.  If you're running this on localhost, could you have a local firewall that is blocking connections?

Comment: Also, in connect_to_server.js, `const socket = io.connect("localhost:3000", {});` should be `const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000", {});`.  The argument to `io.connect()` is supposed to be a URL.

Comment: @jfriend00 passing the parameters to `io.connect()` didn't change anything; on the other hand, i checked the versions and the server side is socket.io 4.5.2 but i don't know how to check the client version as i use a script tag to "/socket.io/socket.io.js" (that was the only method that worked, another problem that took a whole lot of time to figure out as nothing else was working)

Comment: If you're getting the client from `/socket.io/socket.io.js` and not overriding that on the server, then it will automatically be the correct version so that's probably not the issue.